# Cypress - Iterate over each element that takes to new page- perform some action on new page- Do this for all elements

Tags: cypress

[image]

[image]

I have below issue in cypress:

1. Get all delete buttons.
2. Iterate over each delete button.
3. click on each button.
4. Navigate to delete confirmation page(it is different page all together not a popup)
5. Click on (red) Delete button (will be navigated back to list page)
6. Perform same action on remaining shopping lists

   ```
   cy.get('a[href*=delete][href$=confirm]').each(($ele) => {
   cy.wrap($ele).click({ force: true });
   // on confirm delete screen
   cy.contains('button', 'Delete').click({force: true,});
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try repeating the get inside the loop

```js
const selector = 'a[href*=delete][href$=confirm]'
cy.get(selector).each(($el, index) => {

  cy.get(selector).first()
    .click({ force: true })

  // on confirm delete screen
  cy.contains('button', 'Delete').click({force: true,})

  cy.contains('h1', 'Name').should('be.visible')  // confirm we are back on 1st page

})
```